# Mutt - composing HTML email

Tags: emacs, html, mutt

Ultimately this will come down to the editor; however, it seems appropriate to ask mutt users how they've handled this issue.

I have a folder hook that sets my content_type to text/html when I switch to my work email (required that we use html sigs).  My sig is raw html and comes across perfectly displayed on an HTML capable client.  The only problem I have is formatting the actual email text.

Since the content_type is html (as opposed to attaching my email signature html file, which didn't seem to display on all html clients) - and my editor (emacs or nano) is writing plain text, my new lines don't work.  I'm guessing that I will end up using tr or sed (or a combination) to replace the \n's with `<br>`, but I wanted to see if there is anything more elegant than that.

I've tried putting emacs in html-mode, hoping that it would automatically export html, but that alone didn't do it.

Anyone have any suggestions?

I'm willing to use emacs or nano, but avoid Vi because my muscle memory is so accustomed to the other two

Comment: **replace my newlines with the br tag **   Sorry .. I wrote the actual tag which was filtered out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone have any suggestions?

Well you just have to write html, you can use any IDE of many free and paid available over internet. Some open source being Netbeans, Eclipse et al. So you can edit your html with any of the IDE, All are pretty elegant.

Hope this helps, Mark this as helpful or answered if it answers your query.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I am limited to console based editors.  Reason being, I use ssh to access my machine.  The only problem I have with the final text is the newline.  I was just hoping that there is an editor that will allow me to type normally, but place the appropriate tags in after saving.  For instance, when I use wordpress, there is an option to enter text or visual mode.  If I enter text, when i switch back to visual mode it has added the paragraph and break tags...was hoping for the same functionality, but in a console based editor. TY again for replying

Comment: Well these IDEs work over ssh/scp also, in order to work on remote servers directly from your machine, Also If you give **max-width** to your div or paragraph in which you are writing content it will automatically wrap your text around that max-width. Hope this helps! Please support the answer if it did :)